# working out 3 times a day

Tags: exercise-frequency, overtraining

Five days a week I walk for 1.5 miles (about 20 minutes) in the morning around 7am, strength train in the afternoon (about 1 hr) around 1 pm, and walk again for 1.5 miles (about 20 minutes) in the evening around 6pm.

Would the above routine be considered over training ?

I am not a fitness person. Just training to be in good shape.

Comment: I'm guessing that should say " in the morning around 7**am**"?

Comment: 1.5 miles in 20 minutes twice a day is hardly a "workout". I used to do that every day, 5 days a week, starting at age 5, just walking to and from school!

Comment: @alephzero - yes, barely a baseline level of activity

Comment: @alephzero Uphill in the snow both ways?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Will the above routine be considered over training?

No, because it's impossible for a routine to be considered overtraining. Even a program as obviously impossible for mortals as "600 sets of 3 back squats at 95% 1RM, 7 days a week, with a marathon for cardio" isn't overtraining, because *programs* aren't overtraining, an *individual trainee's response* to a program is overtraining. And even then, it's not a pure program/trainee relationship, but the program/trainee/circumstances relationship. Work or relationship stress, or insomnia, or summer heat, or missing meals can all cause overtraining when normally someone would do fine on a program.

Some people run a marathon every day for a year and aren't overworked. Other people need couch-to-5k programs. That's okay. The question is whether *you* are doing well on this program. Did you add too much physical stress too fast or was this was a gradual increase over time? Do you feel okay with your training load right now? Are you eating well? Sleeping well? Do you feel sore, and if so, is it too much? Do you have trouble getting out of bed? These are the questions to ask yourself.

But I bet that two twenty-minute walks aren't too much to worry about, on top of a strength training program. Make sure you drink enough water.

Comment: +1 `programs aren't overtraining, an individual trainee's response to a program is`.

Answer (score 5):

**No**. 1.5 miles isn't that long but is good to burn some extra calories. Just be sure to change up which muscles you are using (Not only Upper Body for example) in your strength session, then this is a good routine.

**Overtraining** would be if you workout that much that your body can't recover from the damages you are doing to it during your workouts.

I wouldn't recommend working out when you're too sore, give yourself a rest day (Speaking from experience).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the person. My dad, in his 70s now, walk 2-3 kilometres on an average every morning and evening, followed by light Yoga movements. And throughout the day, he would do gardening activities, cycling/walking again to the market or bank, post office, others. He doesn't feel weak after all these.

Also, I have some friends who runs 5-6 kms every morning (sometimes 6 days a week), and in the evening they either play football or lift weight.

If you want to start your fitness goal (I did too), I would recommend increasing the load gradually. By that I mean, during the first month don't lift too heavy.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the above routine be considered over training ?

Most certainly simply no. Depends imensly on the intensity of strenght workout.
I assume you are somewhat fit.
Just make sure you are eating and drinking enough and clean.

Just keep in mind that our bodies were MADE to do physical things, the way most of us live our live can be considered under training...